# getJson load specific data with jQuery is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have this short json file:

```
{"daten":[
    {
        "url":"destille",
        "lang":"de",
        "ausblenden": {
            "parts":"farben, sonstiges, material"
        }
    },
    {
        "url":"schnaps",
        "lang":"de",
        "ausblenden": {
            "parts":"farben, sonstiges"
        }
    }
]}
```

And I want to load just a specific part of the listed data, for example the "schnaps"-part.

```
 $.getJSON('data.json', function(data) {
        var output="<ul>";
        var uri = "schnaps";
        output+="<li>" + data.daten[uri].url + " " + data.daten[uri].ausblenden.parts+"</li>";


        output+="</ul>";
        document.getElementById("placeholder").innerHTML=output;
  });
```

I have no idea how to get this. loading the whole data is no problem...but just one part seems to be tricky.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to get the object whose url parameter has value "schnaps", you might do this :

```
$.getJSON('data.json', function(data) {
  var objects = data.daten.filter(function(v){return v.url=="schnaps"});
  if (objects.length==0) return; // no object has url schnaps
  var obj = objects[0]; 
  output+="<li>" + obj.url + ... + obj.ausblenden + ...
  ...
```

Answer (score 1):

In this part:

```
data.daten[uri].url
```

`daten` refers to an array, and `uri` (which is set to "schnaps") would have to be a key in that array, but it's not - "schnaps" is the `url` property of an object **inside** that array.

You'll need to iterate through or otherwise filter the array and obtain the object inside it that has `url === "schnaps"`.

Answer (score 0):

In your `JSON` `daten` is an `array` but `schnaps` it is not an index on it. You should index it using a number.

May you can convert your data to:

```
{
    "daten": {
        "destille": {
            "lang":"de",
            "ausblenden": {
                "parts":"farben, sonstiges, material"
            }
        },
        "schnaps": {
            "lang":"de",
            "ausblenden": {
                "parts":"farben, sonstiges"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your array is not associative. You should itterate over it like: data.daten[0].url this, because passing a string to the index won't get you anywhere.
You could also try searching for other array search mechanisms that would provide you with the functionality you need by searching with a string.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you cannot choose your desired element by doing `data.daten["schnaps"]`. That datum is in a JSON array, so you should do this instead `data.daten[1].url`, which would retrieve the data you want.